# Do I need to reinstall angular/cli after it was installed globally?

Tags: angular-cli

I am new to angular application, I had installed angular/cli globally via npm install -g @angular/cli, now I want to create another app. Do I need to install angular/cli once again. If not how do I ref the global one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to. You should be able to use the 'ng' commands once it's installed globally. I used their setup documentation for my first angular app. Here is a link https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Comment: when I create new app using ng , It complains angular.json from earlier doesn't allow me to do, I had to rename this angular.json and then I can create any idea why?

Comment: Are you trying to create an application in the same location as the previous app? If I remember correctly, it uses your app name in the folder structure. Try doing an `ng new test-app` and see if that works.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tried to create this app in completely new location, but somehow angular.json doesn't allow me to create new app

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary unless you change the node version, for more security check if it is still installed with the following command

```
ng -v
```

or

```
ng version
```

if it is installed, only the new application must be created with the usual command

```
ng new my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to install angular cli globaly `npm install -g @angular/cli` in two cases

- install angular cli for the first time on this machine.
- update angular cli version.

  create a new angular project

```
 ng new angular-starter-app
```

> run this command `npm install -g @angular/cli` will install angular cli latest version in case you have old version but this will not have any effect of any old version generated project because an angular project has dev dependency to the cli with the same version at the time it create ,you will get a warning and the local version will be used.

check other cli option  [here](https://angular.io/cli)